# What is @-webkit-viewport?

Tags: html, css, webkit

I came across this webkit CSS selector @-webkit-viewport today and trying to understand what it does ? There does not seem to be any documentation on this. I tried

```
@-webkit-viewport {
    max-height: 100px;
    min-height: 100px;
}
```

and

```
@media all {
    @-webkit-viewport {
        max-height: 100px;
        min-height: 100px;
    }
}
```

but both are not working. Can someone please explain what @-webkit-viewport does and an example of using it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can define meta name as viewport and then you can use it for different mobile browsers like this:

Include it in your `<head />`:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320, initial-scale=0.5">
```

Css:

```
@-o-viewport { /*for opera browser*/
    width: 300px;
    zoom: 1;
}
@-webkit-viewport { /*for webkit browser*/
    width: 320px;
    zoom: 0.5;
}
@-ms-viewport { /*for internet explorer*/
    width: 320px;
    zoom: 0.5;
}
```

Currently firefox and safari doesn't support this.

You may also [see mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@viewport).

Here's a nice [blog](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/thinking-ahead-css-device-adaptation-with-viewport) about this.

Comment: Not recommend to set fixed width like `320px`. Set with percentage whenever possible.

Comment: `But currently firefox and safari doesn't support this.` - why are you using those vendor prefixes in  your answer then? it is confusing.

Comment: would be better as we don't know whether, in future, they need vendor prefixes or not.. unless you knew it.. :P

Comment: Hmm, yeah, I removed that. Thanks.

Comment: And also, as per the docs, there is no need to `-webkit` prefix. I could be wrong though.

Comment: No. There's -webkit prefix supported by chrome. Wait I will show you a blog.

Comment: I just found a [github](https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/master/LayoutTests/css3/device-adapt/viewport-at-rule-parsing.html)

Comment: You show how to use it but you **don't** explain *what it is*!

Comment: You didn't see at top in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

It let's you edit the style of the content area depending on the browser Agent, and should be in your head section.

```
    <style type="text/stylesheet">
        @-webkit-viewport   { width: device-width; }
        @-moz-viewport      { width: device-width; }
        @-ms-viewport       { width: device-width; }
        @-o-viewport        { width: device-width; }
        @viewport           { width: device-width; }
    </style>
```